# Android 2 bottom buttons side by side

Tags: android, button, layout

How I can do this? I'm trying with Android studio but without success!

[image: http://s29.postimg.org/tv607t9tz/asd.png]

Comment: its always helpful to post your layout xml and/or activity class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orienation, that contains the two buttons. The `LinearLayout` width is `match_parent`. The width of the two buttons is 0dp and assign both `weight` 1

Comment: Ok, it works but the buttons have left,right and bottom margins.. why?

Comment: I can't say anything without seeing the layout